service-worker process seems to stop on page navigation
I am a bit of a PWA novice - and I'm trying to use messaging from the front-end to a service-worker.js to trigger the download of images one by one on a page. This causes those images to be auto-cached through my fetch event. To track things - I have a simple dial on each page to indicate how many images are cached.
The code is all working ok and will do as requested if I sit and watch, BUT if I navigate to a new page whilst the download is still running then the download seems to stop (and I see no further console messages being added, no dev-tools debug breakpoints hitting, and no further progress showing on the dial when I return to the original page).
What am I doing wrong here? [My premise here is that [I believe] service-worker processing should continue running regardless of page navigations]
service-worker.js:

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if ( event.data && typeof(event.data)=='string' ) {
        let firstPart, secondPart;
        if (event.data.indexOf(':') > 1) {
            let parts  = event.data.split(':');
            firstPart  = parts.shift();
            secondPart = parts.join(':');
        }
        else {
            firstPart  = event.data;
            secondPart = '';
        }
        if (firstPart === 'download-images') {
            let parts  = secondPart.split(':');
            let id  = parts.shift();
            secondPart = parts.join(':');
            let images= secondPart.split(',');
            doImagesDownloadLoop(images, id)
                .then(() => {
                    doPostMessage('showmsg:Pages download complete');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    doPostMessage(`showmsg:Failed to download or filter images: ${error}`);
                });
        }
    }
});

async function doImagesDownloadLoop(images, id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        try {
            await downloadImage(images[i], i, images.length, id);
            let percentageLoaded = ((i + 1) / images.length) * 100;
            doPostMessage(`update-dial:${id}:${percentageLoaded}`);
        } catch (error) {
            doPostMessage(`showmsg:Failed to download or filter image ${i + 1}/${images.length}: ${error}`);
        }
    }
}

